# Fourier transform of circulant or cyclic permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, fourier-transform, circulant-matrices, permutation-matrices

I understand that a circulant is expanded as a polynomial in P

$$C = C_{0} P + C_{1} P^{2} + \dots + C_{n} P^{n}$$

I also know that the columns of the Fourier matrix $F$ are the eigenvectors of $P$ and therefore eigenvectors of $C$.

What I don't understand is how $F$ times the coefficients vector $C_{0} C_{1} \cdots C_{n}$ gives the eigenvalues of $C$. Also, because $PF=F\Lambda$, $F^{-1}PF=\Lambda$ gives the eigenvalues of P, what does $FP$ give?

Comment: I presume $P$ is the circulant with top row $\pmatrix{0&1&0&\cdots&0}$?

Comment: yes it is, is it because the fourier matrix is symmetric so the left and right eigenvectors of C are the the same?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what this "Fourier matrix" is, but I doubt whether it is symmetric.

Comment: It is the discrete fourier matrix given here..https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/positive-definite-matrices-and-applications/complex-matrices-fast-fourier-transform-fft/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses3.2sum.pdf

Comment: @AnginaSeng See this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix). It is indeed symmetric (but not Hermitian).

Answer (score 0):

Your last paragraph is the result of an interesting coincidence: it turns out that $F$ is not only the matrix of eigenvectors of $P$, it is also the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) associated with the eigenvalues of $P$.  The Vandermonde matrix has the property that for any values $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$ and polynomial $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_nx^n$, we have
$$
V(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n) \pmatrix{a_0\\a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n} = \pmatrix{p(x_0)\\p(x_1)\\ \vdots \\ p(x_n)}.
$$
Now, let $p(x) = C_0 + C_1 x + \cdots + C_n x^n$.
Since $F = V(\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ where $\lambda_0,\lambda_1\dots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $P$, we have
$$
F \pmatrix{C_0\\ C_1 \\ \vdots \\ C_n} = \pmatrix{p(\lambda_0)\\ p(\lambda_1) \\ \vdots \\ p(\lambda_n)},
$$
which are indeed the eigenvalues of the circulant matrix $C = p(P)$.

---

To figure out what $FP$ is, we could note that
$$
FP = (P^TF^T)^T = (P^{-1}F)^T = (F\Lambda^{-1})^T = \Lambda^{-1}F.
$$

Comment: Thanks, but if I just use the left eigenvector multiplication:       $F^{T}P=\Lambda F^{T}$  but F is symmetric then $FP=PF=\Lambda F$ should I also complex conjugate the left eigenvector?

Comment: @Str91 It should be $F^*P = \Lambda F^*$ (so indeed, use the conjugate of the transpose)

Comment: Because $P$ is real, we have $$\overline{F^*P} = \overline{\Lambda F^*} \implies F^TP = \bar \Lambda F^T \implies FP = \bar \Lambda F$$